# Setting iteration limit with lmfit and differential evolution method

Tags: python, lmfit, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to fit a set of data using the lmfit package. As a minimization routine I have chosen differential_evolution (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) and I would like to limit the maximal number of iterations performed.

According to the lmfit manual (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#the-minimize-function), I can pass keyword arguments via the minimize function to the underlying scipy minimizer using the **fit_kws dictionary.

I have tried several options, to pass the keyword to the fit routine. Examples are:

```
fit_kws={'maxiter':20}
out = minimize(f2min, fit_params, args=(q, Iexp, errI), iter_cb=printout, method='differential_evolution', **fit_kws)
```

or

```
out = minimize(f2min, fit_params, args=(q, Iexp, errI), iter_cb=printout, method='differential_evolution', fit_kws={'maxiter':20})
```

or

```
out = minimize(f2min, fit_params, args=(q, Iexp, errI), iter_cb=printout, method='differential_evolution', maxiter = 20)
```

I don't get any error message, but the maxiter is simply ignored. I would simple expect that after 20 iterations (I've tried also with larger numbers), the fit procedure would stop. Also, if I define the fit_kws as

```
fit_kws={'maxiter':a}
```

which is nonsense, I would expect an error, which I don't get.

Could you please help me understanding how to pass some parameters to the underlying scipy.optimize function?

Comment: Try simply passing `maxiter=20` to the function istead of the dict, what happens then?

Comment: Nothing, as also nothing happens if I pass maxiter='a'.

Comment: Kinda guessing here since I can't reproduce anything, but try to pass `kws={'maxiter'=20}` instead of `fit_kws={'maxiter'=20}`.

Comment: Using `minimize(..., method='differential_evolution', maxiter=20)` should work. If you are sure it is not working (what is the evidence? FWIW, with `differential_evolution`, `maxiter` means "maximum number of generations"), post a question on the mailing list or submit a bug report.

Comment: Yes, indeed the maxiter value is not the maximum number of iterations, but the number of generation. Thus indeed, thanks for your suggestion. It did work at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although in my case an error was raised, see for this the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58727732/7415412).

In short, you can pass keyword arguments tothe underlying solver with the keyword argument `options`:

```
fit = fitter.minimize(method='differential_evolution', options={'maxiter':20})
```

or more specifically for your examples above:

```
out = minimize(f2min, fit_params, args=(q, Iexp, errI), iter_cb=printout, method='differential_evolution', options={'maxiter':20})
```